# return subdocuments from array of id's with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, mongoose, subdocument

I currently have an array of multiple id's which reference subdocuments. What I need to do is search collections for these Id's and return the information associated with them.

```
var ids =['58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc0','58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc0'];
User.aggregate(
      {$unwind : "$position"},
      {$match:{'_id': { $in: [

     // need to reference the ids array here

    ]}
}
}, function(err, docs){
     console.log(docs);
});

});
```

My user schema is as follows:

```
var User = new Schema({
id: String,
name: String,
position: [{
          _id:String,
          title: String,
          location: String,
          start: String,
          term:Number,
          description:String,
          date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
```

So basically what I need to do is return the entire Position subdocument if it matches an id from the array. Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? Are you searching position inside a single user document ?

Comment: @Veeram my mongo version is v3.2.10. What I have is multiple users(user schema) and within these users there are various position subdocuments (all of which have individual id's associated with them) what I need to do is search all of the users , unwind the position subdocuments and return the ones which match the id's in the array of id's I have

Comment: Try `User.aggregate(
          { $unwind : "$position" },
          { $match: { "position._id": { $in: ids } } },
          { $project: { "position": 1 } } 
     )`

Comment: @Veeram Im unfortunately getting a blank array back from that code :(

Comment: Looks like aggregate doesn't do casting ids from string to objectIds. Try casting the `_ids` to `var ids =[mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc0'), mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc0')];` before sending it to `$match`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram thats works now! :) thanks for the help

Comment: Actually, @Veeram would you know how to order the results by the order of the array? Right now it seems to be in the order of how they are found in the database, for example the second ID in the array is actually before the first one in the database, so that seems to be coming back first...

Comment: Np. This is not possible for 3.2 version as far as I know. You will have to sort them by some field explicitly for definite order before projecting. Other option will be go through them and sort on client side after getting results. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7528